# issues installing perl DBI-mysql in windows

Tags: mysql, database, perl, database-connection

I have downloaded and installed **ActivePerl** on my Windows 7-64 machine. Everything went smooth, and also loaded the `perl` interpreter into my `Eclipse` platform.
However, when I try to access a `localhost` MySQL database, I got the following error:

```
$database = "<database>";
$host = "localhost";
$user = "<user>";
$password = "<password>";

#connect to MySQL database
my $db = DBI->connect(
            "DBI:mysql:database=$db:host=$host",
            $user,
            $password
    ) or die "Can't Connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

then I get the following error:

```
     install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Users/souzamor/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.epic.debug C:/Users/souzamor/workspace/Parser C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at (eval 3) line 3.
    Perhaps the DBD::mysql perl module hasn't been fully installed,
    or perhaps the capitalisation of 'mysql' isn't right.
    Available drivers: CSV, DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, ODBC, Oracle, Pg, Proxy, SQLite, 
Sponge.
     at C:/Users/souzamor/workspace/Parser/Parser.pl line 14.
```

Also, when I try to install DBD-Mysql I get:

```
C:\Perl64\bin>ppm install DBD-Mysql
ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides DBD-Mysql
```

I have installed `DBI`, `Data-Table`, but I can't install `DBD-Mysql`. Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: Case is important. It's DBD-mysql, not DBD-Mysql.

Comment: @DaveCross I've tried both `DBD-mysql` and `DBD-Mysql`. I had the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [DBD-mysql ppm info page](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/DBD-mysql/), [build log file](http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x64/5.16/1600/C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.021.d/log-20120606T012249.txt).

ActiveState tries to apply some local patches before building, but it fails. Contact them to have this fixed. Revert to 5.14 meanwhile for which a PPM package exists, or try to build DBD-mysql manually on your own system if you know how.

Comment: Is it only available with a Business license?

Comment: No, what gave you the idea? This plainly is a technical problem, there, and someone needs to look into it.

Comment: The link for the info page has links to "download the ppmx package", when you click it asks for the user/password for Business, that's waht gave him the idea. I just had the same experience. :(

Answer (score 0):

If your using a Linux machine you can install the package using and package manager. The package i believe is **libdbd-mysql-perl**

If that doesn't work you can console in to CPAN directly and install it using the command **install DBD::mysql**

This link has a bunch of different options you can try if what i mentioned above doesn't work

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RUDY/DBD-mysql-2.9008/INSTALL.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the DBD::mysql module. ActivePerl comes with the ppm utility to install modules.

i.e., from the command line run this command:
    Quote
**ppm install DBD::mysql**

regards,
samadhan